# Problems with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm sending an image with ajax, but in my .php file never enter to the function.
If in the url, in ajax, I just write "xajax_publicar.php" and the log (FB::log("something")) I put this in the php file out of the fuction, this it shows in the console, but in the function, never enter there.

**My JS**

```
function GuardarImagen(id)
{
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#imagen1')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('imagen-'+i, file);
});

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'xajax_publicar.php/GuardarImagen',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Datos : " + data);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

**This is my PHP File**

```
function GuardarImagen()
{
    try 
    { //Here i'm doing anything, FB LOG is a log in php
       $nombre  = $_FILES["imagen-0"]["name"];

       FB::log("In te function");   
       echo "Hola"; 
   } 
   catch (Exception $e) 
   {

    }
}
```

I save first a "Publication", then I save Images and call the function in the JS from the same file php with xajax. This is my function that save "Publication".

```
function Publicar($titulo,$des,$noticia,$torneo,$jornada)
{
    try 
    {
        $respuesta = new xajaxResponse();
        $funciones = new N_Publicacion();
        $objpublicacion = new EN_Publicacion();
        $iduser = $_SESSION["iduser"];
        if($torneo == 0)
        {
            $torneo = null;
            $jornada = null;
        }
        $objpublicacion->setTitulo($titulo);
        $objpublicacion->setDesc($des);
        $objpublicacion->setId_usuario($iduser);
        $objpublicacion->setIs_noticia($noticia);
        $objpublicacion->setId_torneo($torneo);
        $objpublicacion->setId_pro($jornada);
        $id_pbl = $funciones->Guardar($objpublicacion);
        if($id_pbl!= 0 || $id_pbl!=null)
        {
        $respuesta->call("GuardarImagen",$id_pbl);
        }
        else
        {
            $respuesta->call("Informar","- Ha ocurrido un problema al 
            publicar. Intente nuevamente.");
        }
        return $respuesta;

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us please, how do you call your `GuardarImagen` function

Comment: I call from the same file php "xajax_publicar.php".  I use xajax for somethings. $respuestaXajax->call("GuardarImagen",$id_pbl);

Comment: @NikitaU. there I edit and write that function.

Comment: are you sure that `$id_pbl!= 0 || $id_pbl!=null` is true?

Comment: yes, I confirmed that. @NikitaU.